# OPNsense with Radius Accounting

Tags: radius, freeradius, opnsense

I've been testing OPNsense radius accounting by following this document,

https://docs.opnsense.org/manual/how-tos/accounting.html

I am able to authenticate user through the captive portal but there is no 'reply-message' being shown on the user side after successfully logged in.

From the code there is a reply-message per below

```
Reply-Message = "Hello, %{User-Name}"
```

Any input or guidance on this? I am planning to customize the Reply-Message and will show some information after user successfully log in through the captive portal.

Thanks!